# Merge Database with Another Database WordPress

Tags: mysql, wordpress

We are taking ownership of our WordPress site are now going to manage it in-house. The company who was previously managing it for us was hosting our site on SiteGround. They sent over a folder with a zip file and an SQL file. I have already imported the "wp-content" file to the site, I just need to import the data from the SQL file into our new database.

I have previously tried to import the SQL file and then change the table prefix in wp-config.php, but after I do this, I can no longer log into the admin portal. I also noticed that the SQL file does not have a user's table. I also tried changing the prefixes of all of the default tables to match the one of the imported database. Can I merge the two databases so I can still have that users table, or should I let the company know, so they can resend the SQL file?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Importing the DB into your environment should be straight forward. You need all tables in the SQL. You shouldn't need to merge anything. Get a new SQL import file from the company.

Comment: There are a few more entries you need to change in the usermeta table to match the new prefix. Do a search for "Changing WP DB Prefix" and you'll get lots of useful resources.